# I am getting errors in this K&R c language book exercise2.3

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I am just a beginner programmer, so i can not find what i am doing wrong.I am getting errors such as : subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector on line 37 and expected expression before ']' token online 34.can someone explain me please.

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define max 20

int htoi(char s[],int lim);
int digitval(char d[]);

int main(){
    int i,h;
    char hex[max];
    for(i=0;i<=max && (h=getchar())!=EOF && h!='\n' ;i++){
        hex[i]=h;
        if(hex[i]=='\n'){
            hex[i]=h;
            i++;
        }
    }
    hex[i] = '\0';
    htoi(hex,i);
    return 0;
}

int htoi(char s[],int lim){
    int i,digit;
    int c=0;
    int mul=1;
    for(i=lim;i>=0;i--){
        digit = digitval(s[i]);
        c = c + (digit * mul);
        mul = mul * 16;
    }
    printf("%d",c);
    printf("%s",s);
}

int digitval(char d[]){
    d[] = "0123456789abcdef";
    int i=0;
    while(i<16){
        d[i]=i;
        i++;
    }
    return i;
}
```

Comment: Which line is the error happening on?

Comment: The declaration of `digitval` says that the argument should be an array. When you call `digitval(s[i])` you're calling it with just one array element, not the whole array.

Comment: What is `digitval()` supposed to be doing? The assignment `d[] = "..."'` is not valid. And then the loop overwrites everything in the `d` array. It will always return 16, so nothing it does in the loop is useful for anything.

Answer (score 0):

`digitval()` should take a `char` argument, not `char[]`, since it's just for getting the value of a single digit.

Then you have to declare a new variable to hold the array of hex digits.

The loop shouldn't be assigning to those characters, it should compare the input character with them. When it finds a match, it stops searching with `break`.

```
int digitval(char d){
    char digits[] = "0123456789abcdef";
    int i=0;
    while(i<16){
        if (d == digits[i]) {
            break;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return i;
}
```

Comment: I made changes as per suggestions. I am getting an output now but its is not converting hex to dec correctly. what am i doing wrong. i am just a noob to this so can you help me?